# How to parse json to object?

Tags: c#, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need help.
I have a json array like

```
{data:
[
    {'Name':'AAA','Age':'22','Job':'PPP'},
    {'Name':'BBB','Age':'25','Job':'QQQ'},
    {'Name':'CCC','Age':'38','Job':'RRR'}
]}";
```

Now, I need get all value of the `"Age"`.

- 22
- 25
- 38

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at using Json.NET? (There are other JSON libraries available, but that happens to be the one I usually use...)

Comment: I was really looking for a long time. 
But because not knowing much about it, so still can not do.

Comment: Please do not answer like this anymore. 
Instead, please help me.

Comment: Well what was the result of your research? Have you tried *anything* yet? If so, which bit did you get stuck on? Show what you've tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Btw, in the question it's not a valid JSON string.

Comment: OP's profile statement is priceless. :D

Comment: It's here.
Thank a lot if you have look it.
https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/695937420449775/

Comment: If you can not help it. 
After this, please think more before you comment on someone else question.  
I do not know I just have to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be so frustrated, you must describe your problem properly and do some research first before asking.

Anyways, as @Jon Skeet has mentioned, you can use [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json). Here's the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) of the same. It has many samples with it.

Or using [JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can create a structure like this:

```
public class FBFriends
{

    public List<FacebookFriend> data {get;set;}
}

public class FacebookFriend
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string age {get;set;}
    public string job {get;set;}
}
```

Then, when you get the result, say `json`-

```
FBFriends facebookFriends = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FBFriends>(json);

foreach(var item in facebookFriends.data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0}, age: {1}, job: {2}",item.name, item.age, item.job);
}
```

Comment: I do not know that it can help me or not. 
But really thank very much for your help.